Process is not running in real-time priority
I have a Fortran based application that is running fine and it provides the correct results when I run it normally (i.e ./myapp); however, when I tried to run it with real-time priority it gives the following error:

linux@AnasPC:~/myapp/build$ sudo chrt -r 99 ./myapp 
[sudo] password for emtplinux:
./myapp: error while loading shared libraries: libmkl_intel_lp64.so.2: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

I can see that this library is installed as part of Intel OneApi, this is confirmed when I run:

sudo find / -name libmkl_intel_lp64.so.2

I tried adding the path to the library in the running cmd using the following but that didn't solve the issue:

sudo LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/intel/oneapi/mkl/2024.0/lib/libmkl_intel_lp64.so.2 chrt -r 99 ./myapp

Please note that I already run the ../../opt/intel/oneapi/setvars.sh to set the env variables.
Anyone has any idea what is wrong?

Remove the name of the file from LD_LIBRARY_PATH, you should just use the directory.

@aviro, thank you very much. I removed the name of the library and it worked :)
